# larvel4 How to get pretty var_dump in built in laravel server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pretty-print, var-dump

Does anyone know how to enable the pretty var dumps that I see in Taylor's videos?
I've gotten them to work on my local mamp server .. but I would like them to also work on the built in server package.

I'm not exactly sure how laravel4 creates the server.. is it using my macs built in apache/php?

Thanks.

Comment: Laravel 4 uses the PHP built in server : `php -S localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 2):

The pretty 'var_dump's you see there are provided by the xdebug extensions. You probably have to install it in the php version laravel uses when issuing a `php artisan serve` or `php -S` command. Please refer to the [xdebug documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) for configuring the pretty var_dump feature: